# How to turn an observable of an array into an array of observables

Tags: javascript, arrays, rxjs

Seems people only ever have trouble turning an array of observables into an observable of an array - not the other way round.

So, given an observable

```
 Observable<Result[]>
```

how do I go from

```
Observable<Result[]> to Observable<Result>[] ?
```

The problem stems from the fact that I got an observable of items

```
items$: Observable<Item[]>
```

with

```
Item: {
   value: number,
   ...
};
```

where `value` can take discrete values, say

```
values = [1, 2, 3]
```

I need to create an observable for each value, as each feeds a different component.

So I went ahead and did the following mapping

```
items$.map(items => values.map(value => 
   ({ value, items: items.filter(item => item.value === value) }))
```

which yields an

```
 Observable<{ value: number, items: Item[] }[]>
```

However, in order to assign each value to its component I need

```
 Observable<{ value: number, items: Item[] }>[]
```

How do I get there?

Comment: I'm very confused what's 'z' and 'a'.

Comment: Sorry, I had a feeling that was badly phrased, rephrased the question and hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: If you wanted to make an Observable that emits Observable, that'd be easy. What you want seems to me like you actually need to collect all values from an Observable to an array and when it completes you need to make an Observable from each array item. Am I correct?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your case correctly, but `.flatMap(arr => Rx.Observable.from(arr))` may be what you are looking for: http://plnkr.co/edit/GMLQxmZ8o2KTd6lbdzHm?p=preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small change in your code:

```
values.map(value =>
  items$.map(items => 
    ({ value, items: items.filter(item => item.value === value) })
  )
)
```

`map` operator actually creates a new observable

Comment: Please note - your answer does not answer the original question `How to turn an observable of an array into an array of observables` even if it does solve the OP's issue. You map an Array to an Array of Observables but do not transform a Observable of an Array into an Array of Observables.