# Getting an array of observables from an observable of the array

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Is it possible to create an array of observables from an observable of an array? That is,

```
Observable<Thing[]>
```

to

```
Observable<Thing>[]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn an observable of an array into an array of observables (RxJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113681/how-to-turn-an-observable-of-an-array-into-an-array-of-observables-rxjs)

Answer (score 2):

Yes its possible, what you can do is lets say abc have this observable.

```
const newArray: Observable<Observable<Thing>[]> = abc.pipe(map(res) => res.map((thing) => of(thing)));
```

when you subscribe to it, you will get array of observables.